# Exponents in Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on this identity $\sin^3 x \cos x-\sin^5 x \cos x= \sin^3 x \cos^3 x$
I began working on the left side, but can't seem to reduce the exponents

Comment: I’ve edited the formula – is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If you distribute out as much as possible on the left, what do you get?

Comment: I got sin^3xcosx(1-sin^2x)=sin^3xcosx(cos^2x)= sin^3xcos^3x

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is distributive property manipulations (don't really know how to word it but Ill show you)

${sin^3xcosx-sin^5xcosx=sin^3xcos^3x}$ 
divide every term by ${sin^3xcosx}$

So
$\ \frac{sin^3xcosx}{ sin^3xcosx}$-$\ \frac{sin^5xcosx}{ sin^3xcosx}$=$\ \frac{sin^3xcos^3x}{ sin^3xcosx}$

This equals
1-${sin^2x}$=${cos^2x}$

rearrange with basic algebra

1=${sin^2x}$+${cos^2x}$
Identity is proven